# How to use count of records in Kibana custom visualisation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to do something like bar chart from Vega example below, and I want to see the percentage of a, b, c (that are predifened) from total count of records in the index.
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/layer_bar_labels.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwLCm.png)

Since I am a newby I cannot figure out how to change the example so it takes into account the count of records.

I do not really know where to start even.